# Adding fibre channel PCI Express card to ESX Server

Tags: vmware-esx, fibre-channel, qlogic

I'm currently running several ESX servers using an iSCSI SAN.

I'm in the process of preparing one of my ESX servers for a preformance test using a fibre channel SAN.

I have purchased a Qlogic QLE2460 fibre channel card and I'm ready to install it in a Dell 2950 III server.

My question is will the ESX server recognize the card and load the appropriate drivers neccessary to make the fibre channel card usable? If not what would be the steps to get the ESX system to recognize the card?

This is my first time making a hardware change to an ESX server so I'm a little unsure as to how they will handle the new hardware upon reboot. Any advice is appreciated.

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The card is on the VMware HCL for 3.0/3.5/4.0 so you should be fine.

You can check vmware's HCL [here](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php)

Comment: Thanks for the link Zypher. I actaully checked that our before the purchase. I was looking more for any advice, or steps that might be necessary to get the server to recognize it. I'm hoping that it's as easy as plugging it in a rebooting, but thought I would ask around first.

Comment: Nope nothing special ... if it's on the HCL it'll come up and work just fine and then you just manage it like any other storage device you have (local, iscsi, etc)